# external SATA drive won't mount using SATA to USB converter

Tags: sata-to-usb

So I have one of these SATA to USB converters
https://www.amazon.ca/Converter-External-Universal-Function-Software/dp/B00EHDTRJ6/ref=asc_df_B00EHDTRJ6/

I'm trying to back up old SATA drives removed from a few old Macs.
Success on 2 drives although I found I needed to mount in a Linux (Ubuntu) desktop. Had no luck in Windows most likely because these drives are HFS formatted.

On my 3rd drive however no matter what I do can't get it to mount. The one main difference is that this drive also has a 4 pin Molex I assume for power.

Will I need to supply power to this drive before I can mount?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide power. A good carrier will plug into AC and have a SATA mount that provide proper power.

Comment: Thanks. I only asked because the other 2 SATA drives without molex mounted fine just using the converter.

Comment: Thanks. yes noticed converter has a molex accessory.